# Explain sum(int(td.text) for td in soup.select('td:last-child')[1:])

Tags: python, html, web, tree, screen-scraping

I came across this piece of code during solving a problem. I just cannot understand how the last line of the code before the `print` functions. Please explain.

```
import re
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html'
url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_228869.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), 'html.parser')
s = sum(int(td.text) for td in soup.select('td:last-child')[1:])

print(s)
```

Comment: The print? Or are you thinking of `sum`?

Comment: You don't know what `print(s)` does? Or are you talking about `s = sum(int(td.text) for td in soup.select('td:last-child')[1:])`? In that case, look up generator expressions: https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/ or are you talking about `sum`? `int`? `soup.select`? There's a lot happening at once on that line, you have to be more specific. The code on that line actually could be broken up into many lines, it's just very compact.

Comment: s = sum(int(td.text) for td in soup.select('td:last-child')[1:]) this one only , I don't get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break down the following assignment...

```
s = sum(int(td.text) for td in soup.select('td:last-child')[1:])
```

...into several statements:

```
all_td = soup.select('td:last-child') # get all last TD elements in each TR
rest_td = all_td[1:]  # skip the first TD among those
s = 0  # for accumulating a sum
for td in rest_td:
    val = int(td.text)  # parse the text in the TD as an integer
    s += val  # add that number to the running sum
```

Now you can step through these statements with a debugger, or add some print calls here and there, to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

This is the order of operations:

- `soup.select('td:last-child')` is a method that returns a `list` of selected elements
- `[1:]` is a slicing operation - it creates a new list that skips the first (zero'th) item in the list
- `for td in` is a loop where the items of the list are assigned to `td` in turn
- `int(td.text)` takes the "text" attribute of the object in `td` and then creates its integer equivalent
- `sum()` sums those integers as they are generated